# How do I correctly SysPrep Gen2 Hyper-V image or fix the one I'm working with?

Tags: hyper-v, boot, image, boot-loader, vhdx

My goal was to create a Win10 image (with programs installed) that I could quickly copy and reuse on Hyper-V for testing things.

I created a Gen2 image, installed Win10+apps, then SysPrep'd and shut down. I deleted the checkpoints so everything rolled into the `*.vhdx` file and I thought I was done.

When I create a new VM and use the image, the boot loader is unable to find an OS.

[image]

When I mount the image, I see the normal files:

[image]

What did I go wrong? I have an option for PXE booting...but that seems like network booting.

Comment: i would suggest not to create Checkpoint if you delete them after without applying, please create Screenshots from your config so we see ehat was before and after

Comment: I didn't create a checkpoint in HyperV intentionally, one just was created somehow? I only noticed it when I stopped the VM and realized the `vhdx` was very small in size. I either deleted or applied the checkpoint. So in general, my steps should work though right? Or is there something I have to do during sysprep to allow it to boot?

Comment: how do you sysprep?